# Deja-dup losing its mind every few days on 19.10

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I was using deja-dup on 16.04 with no problems. I recently upgraded to 19.10, and now I'm having problems with it losing its mind every few days.

I set it up initially and it worked fine for a week or two, then prompted me again about whether I wanted to password protect my backups and started a new "initial backup". The older backups are still in the target directory, but it doesn't recognize them as valid backups.
At this point, it seems to do the same thing every 3-5 days. There don't seem to be any useful messages in syslog (or anywhere else in /var/log) based on grepping for deja-dup.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting or fixing will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was backing up to a flash drive and Deja Dup was having a lot of problems recently.

Not really sure what's going on if its some dependency and Deja Dup getting the short end from that or Deja Dup itself.

It did get worse for me after Deja Dup was updated so it feels like its Deja Dup at fault but I didn't really try to narrow it down. its difficult to say if I will though should the problem not go away with my new full backup and format of the drive then I probably will.